# Is it a true practice to access database on each change by the user in Edittext?

Tags: android, sqlite

In an Android application,

I try to register a data in SQL database
The point is I do write and read SQL instructions in an EditText text listener as below:

```
 mLayoutStruct.getLayout_table_3_Row_3_text3().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                 // SQL read and write operation
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
            }
        });
```

Is it a true practice to access database on each change by the user in Edittext?

Comment: well, if you are only reading, then you could cache the database result in a list and query that list, maybe add into that list and store the list as well instead of reading and writing the entire time, but how this improves performance i wouldn't know.

Comment: You can create on list of model class add getter setter in that class and only once assign database values to that list and access that list to and update onTextChanged and once done with updating record you can put updated record in database by this way you will not need to do db operations every time onTextchanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look into this [tutorial link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#5). In real life projects, you would use `ViewModel`, a `Database` and a `Repository` that stays between the `viewModel` and database. In short, on EditText change, you can update(`write`) the database and view model via the repository. And you `read` cached data from the `ViewModel`.  I hope the tutorial is helpful.

Comment: I didn't get it, Would you please elaborate more?

Comment: In big projects, you use `viewModel` for caching data, otherwise your app will read from your database again and again. So for example, if you rotate your device again and again, your app will read data from database again and again and put it on your EditText. That is why we use ViewModel. Now, in many cases, you may have multiple datasource, such as network, database etc (think of facebook or instagram, it fetches data rom network, and stores some data in local database for offline use). So it is a good practice to have a class named `Repository` that handles all the data related work.

Comment: For a complete example with code, please visit the link.  In your case, you mentioned SQL read write operation directly in the EditText's onTextChange method. If I were you, I would create a viewmodel, a repository and use them inside onTextChange. I hope you understand.

Comment: I use SQLite, isn't there any difference?

Comment: In the tutorial, they used room. Room is a library that connects with a database (SQLite in your case). The library simplifies many of the database related codes, such as you don't have to do everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

In real world, you should not perform any query to database or make any API request. You should create a debounce function to handle this.

Let's say you want to query in your database for a searching function. You want to give your user the ability to get the result while they are typing. It will be a very expensive operation if you query to database onTextChanged or methods like that. A debounce function should be implemented in the onTextChanged to make a delay to query using debounce function.

I will never suggest you to use `Thread.sleep()` or some other similar functions like timers. It will be a very bad user experience. If you use timer, then for every click or type, it will create a timer task. You can search about `Timer` vs `debounce` online.

To implement a debounce function in android, I found a good solution [online](https://gist.github.com/rfreedman/5573388)

Comment: The only issue is delay? nothing else matters?

Comment: If you are using sqlite, for sure you will face many problems. In low spec phone if you try to perform query onTextChanged, for sure it will crash.